# HTML5 Video does not autoplay on iOS browsers

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-video

I am working on creating a TikTok component for Web. The component is similar to TikTok. I am looping through videos, so users can scroll through videos.

I am facing an issue with `autoplay` on iOS browsers. Autoplay works on Desktop and Android browsers, but not on iOS browsers. So the issue is that a user has to click on every video to play it. Once they go to the next video then they would expect it to autoplay, but it doesn't as the iOS browser blocks it from autoplaying.

Is there a workaround for this issue?

This is the video player.

```
            <Video
              ref={player}
              src={props.url}
              playsInline
              style={styles.videoPlayer}
              autoPlay
              loop
              preload="metadata"
              onSeeking={onSeeking}
              onSeeked={onSeeked}
              onClick={handlePause}
              onTimeUpdate={onProgress}
              onLoadedData={onLoadFirstFrame}
              onLoadedMetadata={onLoadedMetadata}
              onWaiting={onWaiting}
            />
```

This is the code for autoplay a video once the video loads.

```
const onLoadedMetadata = () => {
    if (!player || !player?.current) return;

    setVideoProps((prevProps) => ({
      ...prevProps,
      currentTime: player.current?.currentTime,
      isBuffering: false,
      isLoading: false,
      playing: !isMobileWeb && autoplay,
    }));

    player.current?.play();
  };
```

Let me know if you'll need more info. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Try to add muted property to Video. [For more](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/)

Comment: @Yogi, It does have a useful solution, but I don't wanna mute my videos because I have to give an unmute button in the TikTok component which is not desired. Is there any other workaround?

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out. By the way, the official TikTok website does it. The videos on their website autoplay on iOS browsers. Do you know how they are making it work?